# In a CI pipeline, how do I run 2 commands in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

My CI file currently has two installation commands that run sequentially. However, as the former does not require the latter to be able to execute, I would like to run these commands at the same time. How do I run these commands in parallel without parallelizing my entire build pipeline?

```yaml
install:
  - docker pull <image>
  - npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use bash syntax;

```
install: docker pull <image> & npm install
```